# Is Phonegap app without user registration is Appstore standard?

Tags: ipad, cordova, app-store, appstore-approval

I see some Phonegap or Native apps in App store which has no user registration inside the app but it has login.  Once I had an app rejected stating My app does not have registration and I am having membership payment on the website.  So, we included an registration inside the app.

Is there any specific process to have apps in appstore without registration, because I see few without registration and has login.  Is is legal as per Apple guidelines.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We had the same issue when we started (on my job), we talked with them and they said that we should use their "Enterprise Deployment program" because it was a App for a specific company and required login. The enterpise deployment program can't be used in some countries and after we told them that, it was allowed without further hassle. Maybe the apps you are looking at are having the same "issue"?

Comment: In our app, we have a site where several organizations signed off so we provide them the app and they can login and use it.  Our web platform has guest org signup also so the app should be public.

Comment: So, if we say our app is globally used they allow without registration?

Comment: Registration can be done on site.. is it ok?  its there in some apps might be yours too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difficult question, especifically taking into account your comments.

If your app lets paid users login, Apple could reject it since you are providing digital goods without their having any part on them.

However, it is also normal that you could have a community of users, and it's not necessary you told Apple all about them (e.g. whether they paid or not). You should give them a demo account though. Even if you have guest access, you should give Apple a demo account so you help them in their review process.

After all, the most important thing is they are human reviewers, so they can say yes or no when they are not sure about approving an app.

As an example, it wouldn't help you cite other apps that have been approved and which have the same characteristics. It's better to focus on explaining your app.

Registration may or may not be required inside the app. It depends on the reviewer. Many apps have been approved without in-app registration, but the guidelines encourage the opposite.

If you're not in a hurry about the review process, I suggest you send the app with the aforementioned tips. If you need it to be approved at the first review step, then I would recommend you following he guidelines as strictly as possible: registration inside the app, in-app payment for subscription.